# What word describes a person that doesn't pay his bills?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, nouns

In the Spanish language there is a word that is used to describe a person that has been tagged as a deadbeat; it is **Largo**. Largo in Spanish means *Long* as in *the measurement of the distance between two points or places, etc*.

If you loan any money to this person, it will be a *long* time before you get paid back, if you get paid back at all, or if you receive any kind of payment. They can also be known as a **Largo** if they are sly, tricky, or conniving with bad intentions.

Comment: You have it in your word *deadbeat*. Largo has no rolled R. Flicked, yes, but usually Spanish uses RR to signal the rolling.

Comment: Corrections: If you lend money to someone, lend, not loan, which is poor AmE. //before you are paid back, no get.

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 3):

In British English 'largo' isn't a word that is used, and while 'deadbeat' can mean that, it is usually more general:

> [**deadbeat**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deadbeat)
> a person who is not willing to work, does not behave in a responsible way, and does not fit into ordinary society
> *Come off it, deadbeat, you're never going to get anywhere.*

---

For a person who doesn't pay for anything, I suggest

> [**sponger**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sponger)
> a person who gets money, food, etc. from other people, especially in order to live without working

or

> [**freeloader**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/freeloader)
> a person who uses money, food, a room in a house, etc. given by other people, but who gives nothing to them in exchange

From Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: I generally write 'Handel's _Largo_' to explain what _Ombra mai fu_, my favourite aria is.

Answer (score 0):

A popular word is **[welcher](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/welcher)**.

> someone who swindles you by not repaying a debt or wager.

It's definitely an insult, and implies deceit.

Answer (score 0):

Another related term is ***mooch*** or ***moocher***, describing someone who constantly takes without giving in return. It's not usually used in the context of a formal bill or invoice, but generally describes a lack of reciprocity and taking advantage of others' generosity. A mooch will seek to get something while avoiding paying for it. A good example might be a roommate who does not contribute to the cable bill but watches lots of TV, or a friend who never offers their share of the bill at a restaurant. It usually describes someone who avoids an informal obligation to pay by letting someone else foot the bill.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are after a word that has a similar dual meaning. You may consider ***delinquent***.

As an adjective, it is associated with unlawful or immoral behavior. Among them, though, is being late with payments.

> **1** : offending by neglect or violation of duty or of law
> **2** : being overdue in payment
> **3** : of, relating to, or characteristic of people who regularly perform illegal or immoral acts
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delinquent)</sub>

As a noun, you will often it see it refer to *juvenile delinquents*. But it also has a broader definition:

> **3.**  a delinquent person; esp., a juvenile delinquent
> <sub>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/delinquent)</sub>

So it can refer to a person that is late in payments, or to a person that regularly gets into trouble with other people or the law.

Answer (score 0):

You could call such a person a **cheat,** [defined by TfD as:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/cheat)

> a person who cheats; swindler; deceiver; imposter.